# the command exited with code 4 with EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact nuget packge

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first, xcopy

I am having an issue when I try to use ***'EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact nuget packge'***.

I have created my model classes and I am also using the new ASP.NET MVC Tools Update MVcScaffolding out for the box feature when creating a new controller. this tooling feature also creates my DbContext class.

as it is explaind here :

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Mix11WebPlatformAndToolsKeynoteDemoScript.aspx

Everything is fine. But, when I add the ***'EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact nuget packge'*** and try to compile, I am getting the following error;

[image]

My machine is windows vista, 32bit and I am using VS 2010 pro if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shared the link of this question on Scott Hanselman's blog post as comment and he gets back to me in an hour or so. the answer is as follows;

> *Perhaps a character in your path? Does
>   it work in a folder like c:\dev?*

and it totally worked. the problem related to folder chars and I tried it inside the c:\apps folder. thanks Scott !